# add legend marker inside the amcharts tooltip

Tags: javascript, tooltip, amcharts, linechart

I have a problem with Amcharts that I would like to ask.

I have a line chart, and I want to copy the preview symbol from legends to the tooltip.
But I don't know how can I do it. tooltip will be such as this pic:

[image]

can you help me to do this?

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/multi-series-shared-tooltip-with-colored-bullets/

Comment: Is there any option for similar functionality in Amcharts3 ?